# interval update debug of uknown interval

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, scheduled-tasks

I've got the basic engine of a game put together rather nicely, my issue at the moment is that while running it from my computer onto my iPhone, I'm getting a strange debug message:

```
CCScheduler#scheduleSelector. Selector already scheduled. Updating interval from: 0.0000 to 0.0000
```

This debug message is being displayed every frame or nearly every frame

Now, I don't have any scheduled updates that are on interval 0, so this makes me think that it must be the generic `scheduleUpdate` command. I did a search entire project to see if any class had multiple `scheduleUpdate`s and none do so now I am confused. Any thoughts?

Comment: It can't be scheduleUpdate because if you run that again you'll actually receive an error message (update selector can't be scheduled again). So it must be a regular schedule: method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally get this message when I schedule something that's already scheduled.  See if there's anything like this in your code:

```
[self schedule:@selector(gameLogic:) interval:1.0];

- (void) gameLogic : (ccTime)dt
{
   [self doLogic];
   [self schedule:@selector(updateTimers:) interval:1.0];
   [self schedule:@selector(gameLogic:) interval:1.0];
}
```

By repeatedly scheduling something inside a timed event, you'll get a warning that you've called the timer a second time.

Comment: hmm.... any way to see which method is being repeatedly called? Or is it good ol' guess and check?

Comment: Well, it tells you the interval.  In my code it says CCScheduler#scheduleSelector. Selector already scheduled. Updating interval from: 1.0000 to 1.0000.  So search for ":)]" (no quotes), that should find any schedule with no specified interval (i.e. 0.0000)

Comment: Figured it out, had to modify a line of code in CCScheduler `-(void) scheduleSelector:(SEL)selector forTarget:(id)target interval:(ccTime)interval paused:(BOOL)paused repeat:(uint) repeat delay:(ccTime) delay` method. new line: `CCLOG(@"CCScheduler#scheduleSelector. %@ Selector already scheduled. Updating interval from: %.4f to %.4f", NSStringFromSelector(selector), timer->interval, interval);`

Comment: I generally try to leave the packaged libraries alone, but if it works it works!